# How to deploy a bottle webapp in production?

Tags: python, mongodb

I wrote a little bottle web application, played around with setup.py, and I'm ready to deploy.

I had two questions:

1. How do I deploy this new web app in production? Do I need a a webserver or reverse proxy? Can my `main.py` be run as a service? How is this typically done?
2. My web app uses a mongodb backend. Is there a way to package that with my application or to require it / look for it / alert the user when the installer runs? How is this typically done?

Comment: This may be a better question for programmers exchange, but I figured I'd start it here.

Comment: A quick look shows http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/deployment.html for deploying apps made in Bottle, but it's a little light and not terribly detailed unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran my Bottle applications on [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/). There's a quickstart template on GitHub for getting a Bottle application online. You could just copy their directory structure and files, add your own, and send it all to the git repository that is created for you. OpenShift uses git when it comes to development, so if you ever make any changes, you just need to commit and push them to the server again.

MongoDB and RockMongo (a GUI for managing your MongoDB database, similar to phpMyAdmin for MySQL) are built in. You get three 'gears' or instances to work with, so the Bottle application will be one, with MongoDB and RockMongo included. You just have to enable them.

Answer (score 2):

[Pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/batteries_included/) allows you for free to test/deploy  a `Bottle` app with `Pymongo` driver. This is one of the webhostings which is python-deployers friendly... If you need something for a serious trafic, then you have to consider a paid programm or your own (virtual/dedicated) hosted server.